# Beggar-my-neighbour possible games

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algorithms, permutations, card-games

How many [Beggar-my-neighbour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beggar-my-neighbour) possible games are there?

There are **5** types of card: a, b, c, d, e.

In a bundle of **52** cards there are **4** cards of type **a**, **4** of type **b**, **4** of type **c**, **4** of type **d** and **36** of type **e**.

I'd like to know the number of permutations of the following array and how I can get through all of the permutations using an algorithm:

$$\underbrace{\text{a a a a b b b b c c c c d d d d e e e . . . e}}_{\text{52 cards in all}}$$

Obviously all the elements with the same name are interchangable.

$ \quad$
$ \quad$

I'm programming a C++ program that looks for infinite games. The game logic already works (I've compared five real games with five computer ones and the results were right). But now it only resolves a game at a time, and I have to manually give it the deck of cards. So I need an algorithm that goes through all of the possible games and tests them. (Even if $6.54\cdot10^{20}$ is really big)

By now I thought of this:

- Divide the problem into simpler ones: first I choose the position for the **a**'s (in **52** places), then for the **b**'s (in **48** places), then for the **c**'s (in **44** places), and at the end I choose the position for the **d**'s (in 40 places).
- Every time I call a function named, let's say, `next_permutation()`, I advance to the next possible places for **d**. When I got through all **d**'s permutations I advance to the next **c** possible places. The same goes for **b**'s and then **a**'s.
- Store 4 numbers nA, nB, nC, nD. Every number represents the current permutation of the letters (as I said above). When I reach the maximum number of **d**'s ${52 \choose 4}$ I increase **nC** by **1** and reset **nD** to **0**. When I reach the maximum number of **c**'s ${48 \choose 4}$ I increase **nB** by **1** and reset both **nC** and **nD** to **0**. When I reach the maximum number of **b**'s ${44 \choose 4}$ I increase **nA** by **1** and reset **nB**, **nC** and **nD** to **0**.

So I only have to figure out how to go through all of the possible combinations of 4 cards of the same type in a deck of 52, 48, 44 and 40 cards.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get help rather than downvotes or votes to close if you edit the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck. Can you solve a smaller version of your problem, with a smaller deck and fewer kinds of cards?

Comment: Perhaps *counting* the number of arrangements of items (containing repetitions, i.e. the cards of a same type) is your goal (this is what a *multinomial* coefficient does), but "how I can get t[h]rough all of the permutations using an algorithm" suggests instead you want to *list* all the possible arrangements (efficiently).  Can you clarify the goal here?

Comment: @EthanBolker I edited my question and added all the things I know so far. Is it ok now?

Comment: @hardmath I added an explanation.

Comment: So in short, you want to generate-and-test all the possible (representative) games.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I'm trying to do. Even with the best algorithm it would take a whole lot of time, but I'm doing this mainly for learning/practicing purposes so it'll be fine just to try a little fraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $52 \choose 4$ ways to choose where the a's go.

There are then $48 \choose 4$ ways to choose where the b's go.

There are then $44 \choose 4$ ways to choose where the c's go.

There are then $40 \choose 4$ ways to choose where the d's go.

That leaves the rest of the $36$ slots to put the e's.

The number of ways to arrange these is then

$${52 \choose 4}\cdot{48 \choose 4}\cdot{44 \choose 4}\cdot{40 \choose 4}\approx6.54\cdot10^{20}$$